# How to pass in javascript variables into a Rails controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, gmaps4rails

I'm working with gmap4rails for a small project of mine. I want to pass in the latitude and longitude values from the user's current location and set those values into my model called Pet. The pet model belongs to the user model and the user model has many pets. I'd like to be able to do this whenever a new pet is created so that the pet adoption information has coordinates.

I understand that for the AJAX request, it requires a url to understand which path it should take. I'm not sure how to add the path into the url parameter since a pet belongs to the model. I did a rake routes to see which route to use and ideally I should use the POST route which was:

```
/users/:user_id/pets(.:format)
```

Do I copy that into the url as it is or do I need to somehow get the user_id with js?

So far, I have created a js file that looks like this:

```
var lat;
var lon;

$(document).ready(function() {
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setLatLon);
}

function setLatLon(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
}
//function for logging in and passing lat and lon to the controller
$(function() {
    $("#save").click(function() {
        //create ajax request
        console.log("creating ajax request")
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "users/pets",
            data: 'lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon
        })
    });
});
});
```

Pet Model:

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :species, presence: true
    validates :breed, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true

    def self.setCoords(lat, lon)
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
    end
end
```

Pet_controller create def:

```
def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @pet = @user.pets.create(pet_params)
    @pet.setCoords(params[:lat], params[:lon])
    if @pet.save
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else 
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Error in the console:

```
creating ajax request getCoords.js?body=1:17
POST http://localhost:3000/users/1/pets/users/pets 404 (Not Found) jquery.js?body=1:9667
POST http://localhost:3000/users/1/pets 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js?body=1:9667
```

Would I be better off trying to save the js file as a js.erb file? I thought that maybe I could embed the route I got from rake routes...

Comment: What is the current URL you are in?

Comment: There are a few things wrong with the implementation. On click There are 2 POST requests `POST http://localhost:3000/users/1/pets/users/pets 404 (Not Found)` and 
`POST http://localhost:3000/users/1/pets 500`

Comment: The second request does reach the server, but there is an error in  the code

Answer (score 0):

> Do I copy that into the url as it is or do I need to somehow get the user_id with js?

If you read the error in the console that you included at the end of your post, you'll see that you are sending two AJAX requests. Like Santosh says in comments, you should find out why and fix this. To explain the errors though, the first one is being sent to users/1/pets/users/pets because your ajax call's url option is set to 'users/pets', which appends that to the default route, and that route does not exist (hence the 404). The second AJAX request is sent to the correct URL but returns a 500 error. If you look at your server console you will see a message along those lines. (Tip: Whenever the browser console reports `500 (Internal Server Error)`, look at your server terminal or logs for details.)

Your other code also has some issues. First, you have defined setCoords as a class method inside your model (with `self.setCoords`) but in your controller you're calling it on an instance of that class (@pet). This will result in a NoMethodError when the program reaches that line. To resolve, remove the `self` from the method definition so that it simply reads `setcoords(lat, lon)`.

Second, is the controller action you are routing the AJAX call to actually accepting AJAX requests? You will need to have a block like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js {
    # do stuff
  }
end
```

If it is the create action that is handling the request, then you will need the above block, and also a create.js.erb file (by default), which will contain the JavaScript code to send back to the browser to refresh the page's state.